# Hover over table column, row AND header column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with a jQuery function for hovering over rows/columns, you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/v0r9kjq7/ This is the code:

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
        <td>Content here</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
width: 100%;
border-spacing: 0;
vertical-align: top;
table-layout: auto;
}
table tr.hover td {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: rgba(30, 138, 228, 0.15);
}
table td {
padding: 0 10px;
line-height: 30px;
background-color: inherit;
color: #3c3c3c;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color:#fff;
}
tbody tr:hover, tbody td.hover {
background-color: rgba(30, 138, 228, 0.15) !important;
}
td:hover {
background-color: #fff !important;
color: #1e8ae4;
cursor: pointer;
}
tbody td.hover:hover {
background-color: #fff !important;
}
table thead th {
background-color: #f0f0f0 !important;
}
table thead th {
padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #3c3c3c;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: left;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('table td').hover(

function () {
$('table td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('hover');
},

function () {
$('table td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('hover');
});
```

How should I change this script so it would also take into account the table header, so the header column would also be hovered?

All help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to update the selector to include `th` elements as well:

```
$('table td, table th').hover(function () {
    // rest of your code...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0r9kjq7/3/)

Answer (score 4):

I missed the hover class in your example

```
.hover {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #1e8ae4;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It then works if you do

```
$('table td').hover(function () {
    $('table td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('hover');
    $('table th:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('hover');
}, function () {
    $('table td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').removeClass('hover');
    $('table th').removeClass('hover');
});
```